# Are there any papers where two (or more) authors share the same full name?

Tags: citations, authorship, personal-name

Because of [reasons](https://github.com/Langenscheiss/bibitnow/issues/59), I'm curious to know whether there are any simple examples of papers where two or more authors have the same full name.

(To be clear: I am *only* interested in *exact* full-name matches. Instances where authors share a last name are so common as to be completely unremarkable, and instances where the first name matches but additional initials distinguish the authors are also reasonably common and *not* what I'm looking for.)

Does anybody have any particular pointers that can be useful?

Comment: A bit in jest, but see [*Another article that makes bibliometric analysis a bit harder*](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~jpfeffer/papers/JPfeffer.pdf) in the 2015 SIGBOVIK proceedings.

Comment: I would imagine there's a parent-child pair out there with the same name that have collaborated.

Comment: I'm on [a paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5488046/authors#authors) with two other Peter Green's, however we do have different middle names and we put our middle initials on the paper.

Comment: an obvious situation where this could happen is a wife and husband team where the wife has taken the name of the husband, and both spouses share a the same first name, for instance Mrs Michele Spaghetti (from a country where Michele is feminine) married to Mr. Michele Spaghetti (of Italian ancestry).

Comment: @PeterGreen Which one is you though

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here's an example with co-first authors who share the same name:

- [Fan Zhang, Fan Zhang, Liyu Huang, Dan Zeng, Casiana Vera Cruz, Zhikang Li & Yongli Zhou "Comparative proteomic analysis reveals novel insights into the interaction between rice and Xanthomonas oryzae pv. oryzae." *BMC Plant Biology* **20**, 563 (2020)](https://doi.org/10.1186/s12870-020-02769-7).

From physics I can only think of papers where two authors share initials and last name, but don't have the full name written out. An example, though perhaps not so simple, is [this one](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.112.091804) from the ATLAS collaboration. Its author list includes two instances each of "A. Gabrielli", "B. Li", "M. Liu", "B. Martin", "C. Meyer", "J. Meyer", "T. Mueller", "C. Schmitt", "S. Tanaka", "P. D. Thompson", "C. Wang", "H. Wang", "J. Wang", "H. Yang", "J. Yu", and "S. Zimmermann".

Comment: Looks like the journal website can't handle that example either. For all authors clicking on the name shows the affiliation, except for the second Fan Zhang.

Comment: "Fan Zhang and Fan Zhang contributed equally to this work." That's ironic

Comment: Well, at least the handling of the `citation_author` meta tags on the html source looks more rational than in the example linked in the question. But the problem with the affiliation popup is really quite something.

Comment: Isn't this why Knuth tries to credit authors in their native script? A lot of information is lost in pinyin.

Comment: Q: Is there a paper where two authors have the same name? A: Here is a paper with 16 pairs of authors having the same names.

Comment: @Stef The ATLAS paper is kinda cheating but it gives us a nice estimation of how frequently we expect it to occur, both in names written in English and those with a native Latin spelling.

Comment: Interestingly, it is possible that Fan Zhang and Fan Zhang don't, in fact, share the same name. That is, the tones (not represented in the paper author list) may not be the same (and tones are as important as vowels in Chinese). Furthermore, even if the tones were also the same, the characters may also be different. An interesting situation, nonetheless!

Comment: Why does the ATLAS paper abstract quote the amount of data in *inverse femtobytes*???

Comment: @user253751 That is rather off-topic, but the unit used in the paper is [inverse femtobarn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_(unit)#Inverse_femtobarn).

Comment: @2ndQuantized Yes this is the annoying thing with being a Chinese academic, they may actually have different names but they look the same when rendered into the Latin alphabet.

Answer (score 24):

A recent example:

Otto , P., & Otto , P. (2022). Impact of Academic Authorship Characteristics on Article Citations. REVSTAT-Statistical Journal, 20(4), 427–447. https://doi.org/10.57805/revstat.v20i4.382

which includes the following footnote:

> To the best of our knowledge, this is the first published article where both authors share their surname and given name, while working at the same university. Thus, the two authors are largely indistinguishable, which highlights the importance of individual author identifiers like ORCID.

Comment: ORCID always makes me laugh.  "What's your orc id?" "Me Grimtooth!"

Answer (score -1):

They do not share the *full* name, only the last name:

[Michalis Faloutsos, Petros Faloutsos, Christos Faloutsos: *On power-law relationships of the Internet topology* ACM SIGCOMM Computer Communication Review, Volume 29, Issue 4O,ct. 1999, pp 251–262](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/316194.316229)

What is also amusing, is that the "Faloutsos" last name is extremely rare in Greece. According to [this](http://faloutsos.com/) they are siblings.

Comment: This was pretty clear from the original phrasing of the question, but I've made it as explicit as I can in an edit. I am *not* interested in anything other than full-name matching.